# How to get the local desktop path of the users file when the application is hosted from server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to run a macro-file that will be present in users desktop via my .net website, hence I would like to know how I can get the path of that macro file in my code and open it.

I am currently using following described code to get the path, and I think that this must be trying to take the path from server computer but I would like to get this from users computer, this particular macro file will open internet explorer and navigate to certain website and download a report to local computer hence I would like this to be run from users side.

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Is it possible to get the path automatically or should i get that from user.
please provide suggestion.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909022/can-i-save-adefault-desktop-path

Comment: Do you want access client desktop file from your Web Application ?

Comment: From digging around in the internet for a while and seeing the reference link it seems that since this code is running from server side its is not possible to access client side files, hence I think I must ask user to provide file path. Or is there any other way?

Comment: @DhivakharVenkatachalam that's what my answer suggest, code you have suggested will run on wen server process not on the client side, thus you need a different mechanism to deal with the client side file processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hosting a website, which is using a web server like IIS and the user access the site using a browser like edge, chrome, now the file is in user desktop, so the main question remains,

> Does the browser process have the access to the file system of the user

Mostly no, especially not via the call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`, this will be good for running it on hosted sever, where `w3p.exe` process is accessing the file system with required permissions

> For the end user desktop

You need to provide the file dialog box, let user select the file / directory and need to plan to serialize the file to the sever (upload) for doing any processing. You can binary serialize the file using a provider like protobuf, msgpack to achieve the necessary functionality

Code you have provided, is good for for the process where you have direct control, like `Console, WPF`, which runs on the system under certain permission and thus access the file system for processing

Comment: Thanks will consider this in future developments.