# C# Console Application Not Writing to Desktop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, environment-variables

I am somewhat new to C# but not new to coding itself. I am currently trying to write a console app to run some processes, gather information from those processes, and then write the values to a .txt file.

I have everything running smoothly in Visual Studio 2017 RC but when I publish and run the program everything runs except the part where the values/data is published to a document on my desktop. Can someone point me in the right direction or inform me why it is working in Visual but not in the program?

```
public static bool WriteData(string DataNeeded)
    {
        string Root = @"\text.txt";
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + Root;

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Header of TXT file");
                sw.WriteLine("Document created: " + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Data being written to text file: " + DataNeeded+ " " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does the document not get created at all?  What user is the program running as?

Comment: Does it throw any errors or if program crashes? The best bet would be it has something to do with the access, does it creates the text.txt on desktop?

Comment: *"I publish and run"* -- By chance are you running as a scheduled task? You'll have to set it up with a little bit more permissions I believe.

Comment: @D Stanley The program does not crash or throw any errors, and in visual studio the text file is created but not when the program is published as a package. @ALI Baig The program would be run as whatever user was running it.

Comment: @TyCobb currently I am not using task scheduler to run this. In the future maybe but right now this is a double click to run process.

Comment: Is it anything to do with Desktop VS DesktopDirectory?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612571/whats-the-difference-between-specialfolder-desktop-and-specialfolder-desktopdir

Comment: @Inneshfree try to create a file in some other directory or give the current user permissions to create the file.

Comment: @Christopher Thomas - That fixed the issue! I was using the logical desktop space rather than the file system location.  IE: Desktop instead of DesktopDirectory.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I cant believe the solution was that simple. I was using a logical desktop space reference rather than using the file system location

```
string Root = @"\text.txt";
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + Root;
```

The above SpecialFolder.Desktop should have been:

```
string Root = @"\text.txt";
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + Root;
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, use [Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) when building paths as in `string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), Root);`  This will prevent double backslashes, or possibly no separator ending up in your final path.