# How to get the Desktop's path?

Tags: c#, getdirectories

I am trying to create a folder in the Desktop (Using DirectoryInfo) - I need to get the Desktop path

I've tried using:

```
DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

But it keeps getting me into the user's Folder (Where the Desktop, Music, Vidoes folders are).

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "Folder111" );
dir.Create();
```

Answer (score 5):

You aren't formatting the path correctly. You're just tacking on the new folder name to the desktop folder name. So if the desktop folder is at `C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop`, you are creating a folder called `C:\Users\MyUsername\DesktopFolder111`, when what you really want is `C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\Folder111` (you're missing the slash).

Use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to automatically add the slash for you:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Folder111"));
```

Daniel's answer may also be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You want `DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` See: [What's the difference between SpecialFolder.Desktop and SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612571/whats-the-difference-between-specialfolder-desktop-and-specialfolder-desktopdir/5612650)